# Blazor WebAssembly or Blazor Server Recipe to authenticate against OpenIDConnect

Tags: c#, amazon-cognito, openid-connect, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I'm a self learning Blazor.
I have an AWS Cognito user pool and I want to authenticate the application using that pool.

I read documentations in several sites and youtube videos but I don't clear for me.

I'm reached a successful authentication in a API (server side) of Blazor WASM, but I can't connect the client to the server side.
Also I'm reached a successful authentication in Blazor Server App, but the callback fails (need to browse "/" again), the logout doesn't work (logs out locally but not in Cognito).

I'm very frustrated and tired.

I will be grateful to anyone who can share a recipe that works so that I can fully understand it and transfer it to my case.

Please, avoid tell me "do this or that", "read this documentation" if you haven't tried it to work.
The React + Blazor or ASP.NET MVC cases are not the same, at least for me who is learning as I go.
Thank you!